# ASP.NET - SqlConnection InfoMessage Displaying multiples

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm running a SQL Server stored procedure on click from a web-app I am writing. The stored procedure may return some message and that message needs to be displayed in the app. However the message is printing multiple times.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    protected void conn_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        lbxMessage.Items.Add(e.Message);
    }

    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbxMessage.Items.Clear();

        String ConnString = "MyConnectionString"
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "uspTest";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        conn.Open();
        conn.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(conn_InfoMessage);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
    }
```

In this example `uspTest` simply prints the "TEST", yet the listbox where it is displayed shows "TEST TEST"

Comment: Why are you using `InfoMessage` in the first place? This is *rarely* used. Results are returned by the stored procedure as *result sets*. The contents of `PRINT` messages aren't results. They aren't even sent immediatelly to the client - the server waits until there are enough of them to send them, to avoid wasting banwidth and introducing latency.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a "progress report" inside a stored procedure perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using InfoMessage to return informational messages. I have the results of the sp being returned in code I didn't post because it was not relevant. The sp I am running has a series of Print statements that need to be seen.

Comment: For a little more information, I am taking a series of stored procedures that used to be ran one by one via the SQL Server Management Studio, and mapping them to buttons so I can run them via an app on my server. But and the contents of the `PRINT` statements is valuable information.

Comment: Don't use PRINT then. Write the info to a log/event table. This will actually take a less space and be faster, since you can store the event definition in a lookup table and only log the event id and data. You can use a table variable and return its contents in the end. ETL jobs and long-running jobs don't use PRINT

Comment: In this case that is not an option. I do not have control over the stored procs. They have to stay as they are.

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();da.Fill(ds);`. You are calling the stored procedure *twice*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is calling the stored procedure *twice*. Once when `da.Fill(ds)` is called to fill the dataset and once when `ExecuteNonQuery` is called.

The dataset isn't used anywhere in the question's code which means the code could be rewritten this way :

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand
{
    CommandText = "uspTest",
    CommandTimeout = 300,
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
};
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    conn.Open();                
    conn.InfoMessage += Conn_InfoMessage;


    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
}
```

The `using` block ensures the connection will be closed even if an exception occurs.

If the stored procedure returns does return results, `ExecuteNonQuery` shouldn't be used. The code should look like this:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand
{
    CommandText = "uspTest",
    CommandTimeout = 300,
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
};
var da = new SqlDataAdapter
{
    SelectCommand = cmd
};
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    conn.Open();                
    conn.InfoMessage += Conn_InfoMessage;

    var ds = new DataSet();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    da.Fill(ds);
    //Do something with the dataset
}
```